# Hibernate filters are not working for APIs returning single result

Tags: database, spring-boot, hibernate, filter

I have added Hibernate filters on my entities . These filters are applied on queries which fetch Collection of entity but not applied on queries which fetch single entity. Below is my code.

**AOrganization.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@FilterDef(name = "OrgFilter", parameters = { @ParamDef(name = "allowedOrgIdList", type = "long") })
@Filter(name = "OrgFilter", condition = "org_id in (:allowedOrgIdList)")
public class AOrganization implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "org_id", nullable = true)
    private Organization organization;

    public Organization getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(Organization organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }
}
```

**Site.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "site")
public class Site extends AOrganization{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "site_name")
    private String siteName;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Site [id=" + id + ", siteName=" + siteName + "]";
    }
}
```

**SiteService.java**

```
public interface SiteService {

       public List<Site> getAllSites();

       public List<Site> getSiteBySiteName(String siteName);

       public Site updateSiteName(Long id, String siteName);
```

}

**SiteRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface SiteRepository extends AOrganizationRepository<Site, Long> {

    public List<Site> findBySiteName(String siteName);
    
    public List<Site> findByOrganization_Id(Long orgId);
}
```

**AOrganizationRepository.java**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AOrganizationRepository<T, ID extends java.io.Serializable> extends CrudRepository<T, ID> {

}
```

**SiteServiceImpl.java**

```
 @Service
public class SiteServiceImpl implements SiteService {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private SiteRepository siteRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Site> getAllSites() {
        Iterable<Site> sites = siteRepository.findAll();

        List<Site> allSites = new ArrayList<>();

        sites.forEach(allSites::add);

        return allSites;

    }

    @Override
    public List<Site> getSiteBySiteName(String siteName) {
        List<Site> allSites = siteRepository.findBySiteName(siteName);
        return allSites;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Site updateSiteName(Long id,String siteName) {
        Site site = siteRepository.findById(id).get();
        if(site == null)
            return null;

        site.setSiteName(siteName);
        
        siteRepository.save(site);
        
        return site;
    }

}
```

**AOrganizationAspect.java**

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class AOrganizationAspect {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.harshal.springboot.springfilter.repository.AOrganizationRepository+.*(..))")
    protected void aOrganizationRepositoryRepositoryMethod() {
        log.info("aOrganizationRepositoryRepositoryMethod");
    }

    @Around(value = "aOrganizationRepositoryRepositoryMethod()")
    public Object enableOwnerFilter(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        // Variable holding the session
        Session session = null;

        try {

            // Get the Session from the entityManager in current persistence context
            session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

            // Enable the filter
            Filter filter = session.enableFilter("OrgFilter");

            // Set the parameter from the session
            List<Long> orgList = getAllowedOrgIdList();
            filter.setParameterList("allowedOrgIdList", orgList);

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            // Log the error
            log.error("Error enabling OrgFilter : Reason -" + ex.getMessage());

        }

        // Proceed with the joint point
        Object obj = joinPoint.proceed();

        // If session was available
        if (session != null) {

            // Disable the filter
            session.disableFilter("OrgFilter");

        }

        // Return
        return obj;

    }

    private List<Long> getAllowedOrgIdList() {
        return Arrays.asList(2l);
    }
}
```

So , hibernate filters are applied if method  `getSiteBySiteName` is called and filters are not applied if `findById` method is called.

**Below are queries :**

1. For getSiteBySiteName :

> select site0_.id as id1_2_, site0_.org_id as org_id3_2_,
> site0_.site_name as site_nam2_2_ from site site0_ where site0_.org_id
> in (?) and site0_.site_name=?

Please help . Thanks in advance.

2. For findById

> select site0_.id as id1_2_0_, site0_.org_id as org_id3_2_0_,
> site0_.site_name as site_nam2_2_0_, organizati1_.id as id1_1_1_,
> organizati1_.address as address2_1_1_, organizati1_.org_name as
> org_name3_1_1_ from site site0_ left outer join organization
> organizati1_ on site0_.org_id=organizati1_.id where site0_.id=?

Answer (score 1):

`findById` is using the `EntityManager.find` method and do not create a query.

Plus Hibernate Filters only work on queries.

You should write a query instead of using findById